# How to get FrameworkElement properties before its unloading

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, frameworkelement

It is need to realize UI settings system - loading/saving some properites of UI elements (which can be modified by user in runtime) from/into persistent storage. For example:

- DevExpress grid control - columns width's, visibility, summary area and so on (this control has set of methods pairs like RestoreLayoutFrom/SaveLayoutTo, but SaveLayoutToStream(Xml) doesnt work in grid.Unloaded handler - when grid is disconnected from PresentationSource)
- grid rows/columns, which widths/heights can be adjusted by user via GridSplitter
- sizeable popup controls

It is easy to set up controls properties from settings storage after controls loading/initializing/etc, but how catch the moment before controls unloading (when they still remains in visual tree) in order to retrieve their settings for saving?

### Short description

I intend to create singleton - UISettingsManager, which inside has a Dictionary with pairs of [element Uid, element settings data]. In visual container (Window, UserControl) this manager can be used in a way like this:

```
public partial class PageHeader : UserControl
{
    public PageHeader()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UISettingsManager.RestoreSettings(myGridControl);
        UISettingsManager.RestoreSettings(myPopup);
    }
}
```

myGridControl & myPopup has unique Uid's (in application scope), so UISettingsManager can retrieve their settings from inner dictionary & apply it to the controls; of course UISettingsManager knows, how to work with some different types of controls.

But when it is the right moment to store settings of controls, which container is Window or UserControl?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Window's **[Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx)** event.

```
public class MyWindow : Window
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
        this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(MyWindow_Closing);
    }

    void MyWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // Save what I want to here
    }
}
```

This would be the safest bet, because you will always, at some point, close the window.

However, there may be alternatives, including the Unloaded event for a user control.

Comment: well, I am sorry because forbid about Windows.Closing event. Most of my controls placed into UserControls, which is changing time to time in the window content area without window closing

Comment: I've updated my answer to show that you can use the Unloaded event of the control, but it really depends entirely on your design.  You would probably save information about an "old" view just before you "load" a "new" view into the content area.

Comment: My application will have some windows, each of them has its own simple controls & UserControls, used for grouping controls into sets. Main window content changes in depending of changing the underlying ViewModel. This approach can be illustrated on the web browser example: main window contains pages (while main model contains set of PageModel instances), each page has a set of workspaces, only one of them is visible (PageModel has List<WorkspaceModel> & CurrentWorkspace property).

Comment: Each WorskspaceModel child class has appropriate WorkspaceView (UserControl). User can navigate through workspaces in the list by changing value of PageModel.CurrentWorkspace, after that PageView.Content automatically changes in order to visualize correct WorkspaceView. So different views loading and unloading and I need to save props of their controls using the approach shown in 1st post (UISettingsManager & so on).

Comment: So the problem seems to find in UserControl analog for unexisted BeforeUnloading event, in other case I need to perform saving in very many & very various places of View subsystem.

Comment: You could create an interface that your Views must implement, which includes a "Save" and a "Restore" method.  Then, in your ViewModel, when you change Views, you call the Save method on the view being hidden (I'm guessing not actually Unloaded), and Restore on the View being shown.  Again, it depends on your design.

Comment: Thank you for advise, Wonko. Today I came the same solvation - create GenericView class based on UserControl & derive my views from this one. Well, working plan for today's evening is ready, :)